# Ruby on Rails - Double Render Error - Redirect and Return

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Error: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)

On update, model checks for template.exists?, if true, download the report AND redirect to parent object. Else, just redirect.

I'm using 'and return' on the tangential side of the 'if' statement, so why isn't that working as expected?

```
def update
  template = resource.check_changes(params[:well_master])
  paramString = resource.to_json
  
  update! do |format|
    if resource.errors.present?
      return render :edit
    else
      if template != ''
        generateWellLetter(template, 'Rpt_Farm_Name', paramString) 
      else
        rec = resource.PERMIT
        format.html { redirect_to admin_well_master_path(rec) }
      end
    end
  end
end
 
def generateWellLetter(template, letterName, params)
  @URL = "#{ENV["API_HOST"]}/api/Document/Generate/#{template}"
  response = HTTParty.post(@URL,
     :body => params,
     :headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/json" })

  Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(response)) do |io|
    while entry = io.get_next_entry
      report = io.read
      send_data report, :filename => letterName + '.docx', :type => 'docx'
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    rec = resource.PERMIT
    format.html { redirect_to admin_well_master_path(rec) } and return
  end
end
```

Comment: No idea what `update!` does in this context but given that it is a block syntax and the error states *"Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return""* I assume that this redirects or renders. So make sure that all the render/redirect calls end with `and return` I guess. Please note `and return` should be probably be inside this block `format.html { redirect_to admin_well_master_path(rec) }` not outside of it.

Comment: You can't both `send_data` and then `redirect_to`. You're trying to respond twice, in two incompatible ways, to a single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rendering way too many times, I suggest keeping any rendering calls clumped together.

```rb
# send_data is like render, you can only call it once
while entry = io.get_next_entry
  report = io.read
  send_data report, filename: letterName + ".docx", type: "docx"
end
```

```rb
# can't send_data and also render
#
# can't use respond_to and respond_with (from inherited_resources -> responders)
# that's what `update!` method is for
#
# returning inside of the respond_to block means 
# `redirect_to admin_well_master_path(rec)` never runs
respond_to do |format|
  rec = resource.PERMIT
  format.html { redirect_to admin_well_master_path(rec) } and return
end
```

---

If you're using inherited resources, then you should probably make use of it, otherwise, it is not helpful and you should just use `respond_to` block with your own logic.

```rb
def update
  template = resource.check_changes(params[:well_master])
  update! do |success, failure|
    # failure - already renders :edit so it's not needed
    success.html do
      if template.present?
        generate_well_letter(template, resource.to_json) do |report|
          send_data report, filename: "Rpt_Farm_Name.docx", type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        end
      else
        redirect_to admin_well_master_path(resource.PERMIT)
      end
    end
  end
end

def generate_well_letter(template, json)
  url = "#{ENV["API_HOST"]}/api/Document/Generate/#{template}"
  response = HTTParty.post(url, body: json, headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})

  # either you're sending the whole zip file or just one file from the zip file
  Zip::InputStream.open(response) do |io|
    entry = io.get_next_entry
    report = entry.get_input_stream.read
    yield report
  end
end
```

*https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources#overwriting-actions*

Comment: Legend. Thank you. It is a bit of a bummer that I can't send_data THEN redirect, that would be the ideal. You would think that they'd allow a target='blank' or meta-refresh option somehow, but nothing doing so far.

Comment: @SeanGillespie that's probably can only be handled on the front end with a little javascript. or redirect first and show a link to that file.